# Pullback of tautological bundle on grassmanian

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$. Let $ W$ be subspace of $V$. Let $r< \textrm{dim} W$.

Then the grassmanians $G'=G(r,W)\subset G(r,V)=G$.
We have the tautological rank r subsheaves (locally free) $S_W$ and $S_V$ respectively.

$S_W\subset W\otimes O_G'$ such that the fiber of $S_W$ at any point $W_1$ of $G'$ is $W_1$.

My question the pullback of $S_V$ to $G'$ is $S_W$, is this true. It seems true fiberwise.

Comment: Yes, this is true, almost by definition.